# C more reliable for networking than Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

## What I'm trying in Python

I am trying to copy a large file over a TCP connection in python (3.6).  I have two functions: send_chunk (sends a little header, then some data) and recv_chunk (parses that header, returns the data).  I split the file I'm sending into chunks and put them on the network as fast as it lets me.  Until around 4-5 MB, everything works.  Then, recv_chunk receives some incorrect data, and everything is toast.

## What works in C

The same operation in C (as demonstrated by netcat) has no problem sending a 100MB file with no errors (also much lower CPU usage).  I looked in the netcat code, and I just see normal-old select and read/write calls.

## Question of the day:

What could be going wrong?  Why does it seem so simple in C but it isn't working in python?

#### code, for reference:

```
def send_chunk(data, sock):
    if type(data) is str:
        data = bytes(data, 'utf8')

    len_str = "{}".format(len(data))
    len_str_size = chr(len(len_str))
    send_data = bytes(len_str_size+len_str, 'ascii')+data
    total_sent = 0
    total_len = len(send_data)
    while total_sent < total_len:
        data_sent = sock.send(send_data[total_sent:])
        print('%f sending %d'%(time(),total_len))
        if data_sent < total_len:
            print('only sent %d'%data_sent,flush=True)
        total_sent += data_sent

def recv_chunk(sock):
    payload_data = b''; size = 0
    len_data = b''; len_size = 0
    # get the length field size
    len_size = ord(sock.recv(1))
    # get the length field
    while len(len_data) < len_size:
        len_data += sock.recv(len_size-len(len_data))
    size = int(len_data)
    # get the data
    while len(payload_data) < size:
        payload_data += sock.recv(min(size-len(payload_data), 2048))

    return payload_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, but copying your data many times make this slow.
Simply use `sendall`:

```
def send_chunk(data, sock):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        data = bytes(data, 'utf8')
    sock.sendall(len(data).to_bytes(4, 'little'))
    sock.sendall(data)

def recv_chunk(sock):
    size = b""
    while len(size) < 4:
        size += sock.recv(4-len(size))
    bytes_left = int.from_bytes(size, 'little')

    # get the data
    data = []
    while bytes_left:
        d = sock.recv(bytes_left)
        data.append(d)
        bytes_left -= len(d)
    return b''.join(data)
```

Comment: sendall() didn't work for us; it errored out much faster with large file transfers.  Did you test across the internet or across a loopback interface?